# Why does my code keep printing None?

Tags: python

I'm practicing binary_search. I want to return 'ban' but my code keeps returning None. I don't know why None is returned although 'ban' is existing. 
*'ban' is variable.
My code is

```
def binary_search(ls,num):
    #print ls
    fir=ls[0]
    last=ls[-1]
    ban=(fir+last)/2
    print ban,num
    if ban > num:
        binary_search(range(fir,ban+1),num)
    elif num > ban:
        binary_search(range(ban,last+1),num)
    elif num==ban:
        print ls,ban
        return ban
ls=range(1,22) 
print binary_search(ls,10)
```

Comment: Please use the editing tools to properly format code

Comment: comparing the result of floating point calulcations directly isn't a good idea

Comment: Probably because the function only returns `ban` if `num==ban`. `return`statement seems to be overindented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed version, see comments below:

```
def binary_search(ls, num):
    # helper function to search the indices
    # we "know" ls and num from the outer-scope, so we'll pass only the indices
    def search(first=0, last=len(ls)):
        if first < last:
            mid = (first + last) // 2
            ban = ls[mid]
            if ban > num:
                return search(first, mid-1)
            elif num > ban:
                return search(mid+1, last)
            elif num == ban:
                return mid  # return the index - not the number itself!
        else:
            return "not found!"
    return search()


ls = list(range(1, 22))  # you should wrap range with list!
print(binary_search(ls, 10))
print(binary_search(ls, 33))
```